# How to use function parameters as class's name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I use the parameters `text` and `name` to work for the class and id's name?

**HTML :**

```
<div id="text" onClick="markClickFunction("text","name");">＋</div>
<div class="name">test</div>
```

**JQUERY :**

```
function markClickFunction(text, name) {
    $('.name').slideToggle("fast");
    if ($('#text').html()=="＋") {
        $('#text').html("－");
    } else {
        $('#text').html("＋");    
    }
}
```

Comment: Offtopic: your HTML is invalid, it should be `onClick="markClickFunction('text','name');">` (double / single quotes).

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple string concatenation, also you need to escape `"` inside `onlick` attribute value or use `'`.

```js
function markClickFunction(text, name) {
  $('.' + name).slideToggle("fast");
  var $text = $('#' + text);
  if ($text.html() == "＋") {
    $text.html("－");
  } else {
    $text.html("＋");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text" onClick="markClickFunction('text','name');">＋</div>
<div class="name">test</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use +(plus sign) for concatenating parameter. Try:

```
function markClickFunction(text,name)
{
    $('.'+name).slideToggle("fast");
    if($('#'+text).html()=="＋"){
        $('#'+text).html("－");
    } else {
        $('#'+text).html("＋");
    }
}
```

Comment: what you mean by ".(dot) for concatenating parameter"?

Answer (score 1):

```js
function markClickFunction(text, name) {
  console.log($(text).text())
  console.log(name.text())
  
  name.slideToggle("fast");
  var $text = $(text);
  if ($text.html() == "＋") {
    $text.html("－");
  } else {
    $text.html("＋");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text" onClick="markClickFunction( this , $('.name') );">＋</div>
<div class="name">test</div>
```

1. Pass this to and the object in function
2. You can access them as $(text) for clicked element and since you passed the DOM itself for second parameter access it as is

Comment: @Rexluvplay glad to help mate happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

For Class you have to add a dot ('.') to the parameter:

```
$('.' + text);
```

For ID you have to add a hash tag ('#') to the parameter:

```
$('#' + text);
```